# How to save EditText content in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have a `listItem` with a `textView` and a `EditText`, it's like a schedule (`textView` shos hour and `EditText` is for user to write a note) so it will be 24 items.

When using a `recyclerView` it updates when I scroll and delete the text I wrote, I tried to implement `TextWatcher` on the adapter but i don't know how to use it.

I already searched how to save text view content but all that I have found are people using array to store the values, I am using a `List`.

**Activity**

```
public class CreateNoteActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   private String[] eventos;
   private RecyclerView recyclerView;
   TextView data;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_note);

       recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
       LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
       layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
       recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


       List<Evento> eventos = new ArrayList<>();
       carregarlistaDoDia(eventos);

       Adapter adapter = new Adapter(eventos);
       recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }

   void carregarlistaDoDia(List<Evento>eventos){
       eventos.add(new Evento("00:00",""));
       eventos.add(new Evento("01:00",""));
       eventos.add(new Evento("02:00",""));
       eventos.add(new Evento("03:00",""));
       eventos.add(new Evento("04:00",""));
       eventos.add(new Evento("05:00",""));
       eventos.add(new Evento("06:00",""));
       eventos.add(new Evento("07:00",""));
       eventos.add(new Evento("08:00",""));
       eventos.add(new Evento("09:00",""));
       eventos.add(new Evento("10:00",""));
       eventos.add(new Evento("11:00",""));
       eventos.add(new Evento("12:00",""));
       eventos.add(new Evento("13:00",""));
       eventos.add(new Evento("14:00",""));
       eventos.add(new Evento("15:00",""));
       eventos.add(new Evento("16:00",""));
       eventos.add(new Evento("17:00",""));
       eventos.add(new Evento("18:00",""));
       eventos.add(new Evento("19:00",""));
       eventos.add(new Evento("20:00",""));
       eventos.add(new Evento("21:00",""));
       eventos.add(new Evento("22:00",""));
       eventos.add(new Evento("23:00",""));
   }
```

**Class Evento**

```
public class Evento {

private String hora;
private String evento;

public Evento(String hora, String evento) {
    this.hora = hora;
    this.evento = evento;
}




public String getHora() {
    return hora;
}

public void setHora(String hora) {
    this.hora = hora;
}

public String getEvento() {
    return evento;
}

public void setEvento(String evento) {
    this.evento = evento;
}
```

**Adapter**

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder> implements TextWatcher{


private List<Evento> eventos;

public Adapter(List<Evento> eventos) {
    this.eventos = eventos;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_listitem,viewGroup,false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    String hora = eventos.get(i).getHora();
    String evento = eventos.get(i).getEvento();
    viewHolder.setData(hora, evento);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return eventos.size();
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView hora;
    private EditText evento;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        hora = this.itemView.findViewById(R.id.hora);
        evento = this.itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_evento);
    }

    private void setData(String txtHora, String txtEvento){
        hora.setText(txtHora);
        evento.setText(txtEvento);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you get what you asked for?

Comment: @amitava yes I did.

Comment: Well I have started experimenting with it after reading your question. And finally I made it working by completely removing TextWatcher. If you want I can post it as answer here to check its merit/demerit.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `TextWatcher` outside the `ViewHolder` it's a super bad choice putting it there.

Create a class for this like :

```
private class EditTextTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
        private int posicion;
        private List<Eventos> listaEventos;

        public void updatePosicionYTexto(int posicion, List<Eventos> listaEventos) {
            this.listaEventos = listaEventos;
            this.posicion = posicion;
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
            listaEventos.get(posicion).setEvento(charSequence.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    }
```

Then when you want to write the note, you do :

```
viewHolder.editTextTextWatcher.updatePosicionYTexto(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(),listaEventos);
```

Inside of your `ViewHolder` you create those two methods, you have to send `new EditTextTextWatcher()` as a parameter to your `ViewHolder` and create an instance of `EditTextTextWatcher` inside like :

```
public EditTextTextWatcher editTextTextWatcher;
```

And then add those methods :

```
void enableTextWatcher() {
        evento.addTextChangedListener(EditTextTextWatcher);
    }

    void disableTextWatcher() {
        evento.removeTextChangedListener(EditTextTextWatcher);
    }
```

And don't remember to add those methods inside your `ViewHolder`

```
@Override
public void onViewAttachedToWindow(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
    ((ViewHolder) holder).enableTextWatcher();
}

@Override
public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
    ((ViewHolder) holder).disableTextWatcher();
}
```

Hope it's clear

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand where I need to write "viewHolder.editTextTextWhatcher..." and "public EditTextTextWatcher editTextTextWatcher;"

Comment: inside your onBindViewHolder method and publicEditTextTextWatcher put it inside your class ViewHolder

Comment: Did you find a solution Pedro?